# JGoodies FormLayout refuses to resize my JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

It seems that the JComboBox is one Java component that **really, really hates** having its height adjusted...I tried countless combinations of `set[Preferred|Minimum|Maximum]Size()` and various different layout managers until the following `GroupLayout` code finally worked:

```
JComboBox cmbCategories = new JComboBox(new String[] { "Category 1", "Category 2" });
...
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(cmbCategories, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
...
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(cmbCategories, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
```

But I've now switched over to JGoodies `FormLayout` which once again refuses to resize the damn combobox! I've currently got the following code:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setLayout(new FormLayout("50dlu, $lcgap, 110dlu, $glue, " +
    "default, 1dlu, 45dlu, 1dlu, 45dlu", "2*(default, 0dlu), default, " +
    "$lgap, fill:30dlu, $lgap, default:grow"));
...
contentPane.add(cmbPanel, CC.xy(1, 7, CC.FILL, CC.FILL));
```

which displays what I want in the JFormDesigner Editor, but upon running the program it simply gets set back to the default!

So what kind of magical hocus-pocus do I need to conjure up to get this to work?! I really don't want to have to go back to defining everything twice in a `GroupLayout`, but after 5 hours of trying to resize a damn combobox I'm on the verge of baldness!

MTIA to anyone that can help :)

Comment: Ended up solving it myself by explicitly setting the look and feel I wanted. Thanks anyway guys :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all we have to avoid setting hard-coded sizes in our components, because Swing is designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and our application must be capable to be executed in different platforms, different screen resolutions, different [PLaF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel)'s and different font sizes. Components sizing and positioning is layout managers' responsibility not developers'.

Now, generally speaking when we want to set a preferred size to our Swing components we don't use any of `setXxxSize()` methods but do override `getPreferredSize()` method instead:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return isPreferredSizeSet() ? 
                super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(100, 40);
    }
};
```

However doing this doesn´t affect the size of the items listed when the pop up becomes visible: cells still having the preferred size determined by the [combo box cell renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html). So, to avoid this undesirable behavior, a better solution would be:

- Set a preferred *width* using [setPrototypeDisplayValue(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPrototypeDisplayValue-E-) method.
- Set a cell renderer and set the cell *height* inside [getListCellRendererComponent(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html#getListCellRendererComponent-javax.swing.JList-E-int-boolean-boolean-) method implementation.

For example:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("This is a cell's prototype text");
comboBox.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        int width = c.getPreferredSize().width; // let the preferred width based on prototype value
        int height = 40;
        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        return c;
    }
});
```

Once again I'd like to emphasize that this is kind of hacky/dirty way to size our combo box. IMHO it would be better don't mess with combo box height at all and just play with `setPrototypeDisplayValue(...)` to set a preferred width in a PLaF safe way.

Comment: Thanks anyway but I've tried both of your suggestions to no avail...I agree that this is incredibly hacky/dirty but I **need** my combobox to be at least 40 pixels high **no matter what**...I've spoken to my teacher again (this is a uni assignment) and he isn't willing to budge at all on this issue...so what the heck do I have to do?! Use a `GroupLayout`ed panel inside the `FormLayout`?? Now **that's** what I call **really** hacky!